# Java - Variable may not be Initialized

Tags: java

Ok, so this program is not working no matter what I try, it just keeps saying the variable tax may not be initialized. The only attribute I can have is income, so I can't declare tax above this code. I find that the code can actually be compiled if I do, and apparently that causes stale data, so it's no use. Please help!!

```
​public double getTaxRate()
{
    double tax;
    if(income == 406751)
        tax = 39.6;
    else if(income <= 406750)
        if(income > 405100)
            tax = 35;
        else if(income <= 405100)
            if(income > 106350)
                tax = 33;
            else if(income <= 106350)
                if(income > 89530)
                    tax = 28;
                else if(income <= 89350)
                    if(income > 36900)
                        tax = 25;
                    else if(income <= 36900)
                        if(income > 9075)
                            tax = 15;
                        else if(income == 9075)
                            tax = 10;
    return tax;
}​
```

Comment: i dont know why this question is marked down. its a legitimate question and they seemed to have attempted to solve it on their own. if we marked questions down because "duh, that's simple", no-one would ask any questions at all.

Comment: This is an excellent example of why `{` and `}` should always be used for `if else` blocks.

Comment: You should really accept [Jason](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34731658/1700321) or [Jacob](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34731498/1700321) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to initialize it like this:

```
double tax = 0.0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you provide no case for if the income is greater than 406751 and have no else case it's possible that you can reach the return statement without ever having initialised `tax`. As has already been suggested, initalising it to some default value such as 0.0 should help, even if you know that it'll never be used.

Comment: Also, if income < 9075, the value would not have been initialised.

Answer (score 2):

There are values for `income` that do not cause `tax` to be set, such as any value above 406751 or any value below 9075.

In addition to setting the initial value of tax to 0.0, your code can be simplified:

```
public double getTaxRate()
{
    double tax = 0.0;
    if(income == 406751)
        tax = 39.6;
    else if(income <= 406750)
        if(income > 405100)
            tax = 35;
        else  if(income > 106350)
            tax = 33;
        else if(income > 89530)
            tax = 28;
        else if(income > 36900)
            tax = 25;
        else if(income > 9075)
            tax = 15;
        else if(income == 9075)
            tax = 10;

    return tax;
}​
```

It is usually clearer to use { and } to make it obvious which code is being executed for the true or false cases of the if statement:

```
public double getTaxRate()
{
    double tax = 0.0;
    if(income == 406751) {
        tax = 39.6;
    } else if(income <= 406750) {
        if(income > 405100) {
            tax = 35;
        } else  if(income > 106350) {
            tax = 33;
        } else if(income > 89530) {
            tax = 28;
        } else if(income > 36900) {
            tax = 25;
        } else if(income > 9075) {
            tax = 15;
        } else if(income == 9075) {
            tax = 10;
        }
    }
    return tax;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to both declare and initialize the variable "tax". Since it is a double, you could give it a value of zero, like;

```
double tax = 0.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

So there are a few issues with your code. Before I go ahead and show you a correct version, I will try to explain to you why this error occurs. If you use a construct of the following form:

```
if (x > somenumber) {
    // do something
} else if (x <= somenumber) {
    // do something else
}
```

You actually don't consider the case x being not initialized (which in Java means x will be *null*). So it might be possible you would return null. To avoid this issue you can set the variable tax to 0 in the beginning. Basically this means you will return 0 if income isn't initialized (or doesn't match up with your if statements, for example if income is 2).

Also your code is horrible to read. Think about adding some extra cases for the taxes in the future and your method will get wider and wider. In addition to that you might want to use { and } to structure the body of your if statements, as already mentioned here.

```
public double getTaxRate() {
    double tax = 0; // could also been set to 0.0 since it's a double

    if (income == 406751) {
        tax = 39.6;
    } else if (income <= 406750 && income > 405100) {
        tax = 35;
    } else if (income <= 405100 && income > 106350) {
        tax = 33;
    } else if (income <= 106350 && income > 89530) {
        tax = 28;
    } else if (income <= 89530 && income > 36900) {
        tax = 25;
    } else if (income <= 36900 && income > 9075) {
        tax = 15;
    } else if (income == 9075) {
        tax = 10;
    }

    return tax; // if income is lower than 9075 it will return 0
}
```

You noticed how this looks much cleaner than your code. The && operators I used basically mean *and*. So only if both of the statements are true the body of the if block will be entered. In your case this allows you to shorten your code significantly.

Besides that I have a question: Does income *has to be* an attribute? I don't know what the whole class looks like but it seems more reasonable to me to hand income as an argument over to the method.